# Rotations from javax.vectmath.matrix3d

Tags: java, vecmath

After a long time, I try to use JAVA again. I'm using the vectmath package, with which I'd like to rotate a 3d vector with a rotation matrix. So I wrote that:

```
   double x=2, y=0.12;
   Matrix3d rotMat = new Matrix3d(1,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,1); //identity matrix
   rotMat.rotX(x); //rotation on X axis
   rotMat.rotY(y); // rotation on Y axis
   System.out.println("rot :\n" + rotMat); // diagonal shouldn't have 1 value on it
```

result:

```
rot :
0.9928086358538663, 0.0, 0.11971220728891936
0.0, 1.0, 0.0
-0.11971220728891936, 0.0, 0.9928086358538663
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't give me what I expected. It is like he ignored the first rotation (around X) and only take the second one (around Y).
If I comment the rotMat.rotX(x); it gives me the same result.

I suspect either a mistake with the print, or with variable management.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods `rotX` and `rotY` set/overwrite the matrix elements, so your subsequent call to `rotY(y)` cancels the call to `rotX(x)`. Something like this should work:

```
Vector3d vector = ... //a vector to be transformed
double x=2, y=0.12;
Matrix3d rotMat = new Matrix3d(1,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,1); //identity matrix
rotMat.rotX(x); //rotation on X axis
rotMat.transform(vector);
rotMat.rotY(y); // rotation on Y axis
rotMat.transform(vector);
// the vector should now have both x and y rotation
// transformations applied
System.out.println("Rotated vector :\n" + vector);
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, I understand my error : I thought that the rotX will rotate the existing matrix. Instead it will replace it by the rotation matrix X(angle). Whatever, the ratMat need to be initialized before using this method.